# Align text vertically center of h2 tag with a background

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I have a h2 tag that has a background image as an icon. I want to align the text vertically within the h2 tag but it doesn't work. I have tried using the `display: table-cell;` but that hasn't worked either. The text may also crossover onto two lines.

HTML:

```
<ul class="FeatureRow">
    <li><a href="#"><span><h2 class="SpeechBg">Need some help?</h2><p>Feel free to get in contact with us</p></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><h2 class="PinBg">Great locations!</h2></span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span><h2 class="ViewBg">View our apartments</h2></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
a {
color: #2b6893;
text-decoration: none;
}
.FeatureRow{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
.FeatureRow li{
float: left;
padding: 10px;
margin: 10px;
height: auto;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #f5f5f5;
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #f5f5f5;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 8px #f5f5f5;
background-color: #fdfdfd;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fbfbfb),to(#ffffff));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fbfbfb,#ffffff);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffbfbfb',endColorstr='#ffffffff',GradientType=0);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled= false);
}
.FeatureRow span{
display: block;
width: 260px;
}
.FeatureRow h2{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 65px;
font-size: 22px;
height: auto;
min-height: 60px;
color: #3F92ED;
}
.SpeechBg{
background-image: url(http://joshblease.co.uk/Apartments/images/icons/speech.png);
}
.PinBg{
background-image: url(http://joshblease.co.uk/Apartments/images/icons/pin.png);
}
.ViewBg{
background-image: url(http://joshblease.co.uk/Apartments/images/icons/view.png);
}
```

JSFiddle Example: http://jsfiddle.net/YPnTp/

Comment: Use a `padding-left:65px` on the `<p>` element. http://jsfiddle.net/YPnTp/12/

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158452/bootstrap3-vertically-align-label-within-h2

Answer (score 1):

In `.SpeechBg`, `.PinBg`, and `.ViewBg`, add `line-height: ##px;`, where ## is the height (in px) of the background images.

Comment: Oh sorry, misread the HTML. I figured you just wanted the main heading (the h2 sections) to be vertically centered, not the <p> elements.

Answer (score 1):

Change your

> .FeatureRow h2 , add **line-height**

css as follows

```
.FeatureRow h2{
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding-left: 65px;
font-size: 22px;
height: auto;
min-height: 60px;
color: #3F92ED;
line-height:2.5em;
}
```

Comment: The third box has text that splits across two lines which makes this unsuitable, any other ideas?

Comment: decrease font size a bit may be 21px