# Bootstrap3 - vertically align label within h2

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing an interesting issue with Bootstrap3 where the label ("Name") seems to be aligned at the bottom of the `<h2>` tag (see the blue box in the image (highlighted by the Chrome dev tool).
[image: label inside h2]

(From the Bootstrap 3 [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#labels) putting labels inside headings seem to be a suggested way)

I can't figure out how to vertically align the label in center of `<h2>`. vertical-align doesnt work on h2 it seems. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17951950/1526703) answer to another SO post  suggests changing the line-height but that doesn't seem to be an intuitive approach since it increases the padding on both sides of h2 (basically increasing the size of the h2 block).

This label is inside a table cell whose code is as follows:

```
<td class="text-right"><h2><span class="label label-default vcenter">Name</span></h2></td>
```

(vcenter is the class I am trying to use to vertically align)

Comment: add demo like js fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like all solutions teach you how to vertically center your `.label` in the `<td>`. However, none of them takes into consideration the difference between ***top*** and ***bottom*** *margins* on the `h2` element.

Basically, you're trying to vertically center with something that's not vertically centered. The only way to account for it is to *raise* the label with half the margins difference, which should be `.5rem`. So this will most likely to the job:

```
h2 > .label { 
   position: relative;
   top: -.5rem;
}
```

If it doesn't, you have stronger `CSS` rules applying and I'll need to take a look at them. Feel free to change `-.5rem` to whatever works for you (in `rem` or `px`).

---

Another approach is to use any vertical centering technique and make the top and bottom margins equal on `td>h2` elements:

```
td>h2 {  margin-top: 1rem; margin-bottom: 1rem; }
```

After this, most of the other answers will work.

Comment: Thanks @andrei! The reasoning makes sense and this worked for me.

Comment: @AnupamJain You are welcome (to SO). Happy to help. Don't forget to up-vote the answer(s) that helped you understand your problem and fix it. It is your way of helping SO community back, by telling future users which solution is more likely to help with a similar issue. If possible, take time to read ***all the answers*** and up-vote each that was helpful to you in any way.

Comment: Sure. Also, FYI, after playing with it a few times, `top: -.7rem;` worked well for me

Answer (score 1):

You can add `display: flex` to the headline tag and then center its children vertically:

```css
h2 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  
  /* Just for presentation */
  background: #ececec;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<td class="text-right">
  <h2><span class="label label-default vcenter">Name</span></h2>
</td>
```

Comment: There is absolutely no point in changing how all `h2` elements behave throughout the app. What happens to a title that should normally wrap on multiple lines and has a `label`? Why do you think people use Bootstrap? Because it just looks good on all devices. Don't break that. There's good purpose into having `inline` labels. What the OP wants is to center the label on its current line, even if they didn't put it in these exact words.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu This is just an example and the OP can move these styles to make them work for this one header in the table row. Also, the OP said he is using Bootstrap 3, so I have used it too, just for presentation...

Comment: That's exactly the problem. It is an example and it serves as example. People that do not know enough `CSS` will copy it and use it, exactly like you provided it. And it will break how Bootstrap displays `h2`s in all the website/app, just because you wanted to vertically center a `.label` on one particular page. Which will not even work as intended if the `h2` wraps on multiple lines. Because in that case the `.label` should be vertically centered with the last line.

Comment: @pan.goth Very interesting! I didnt know display:flex even existed. This worked great for me but the text-right class that I applied on td `<td class="text-right">` seems to have been nullified since it has now moved back to the left (but doesnt show it as overwritten in the Chrome Dev Tool). Any idea on why that would happen? (I haven't used display:flex in the past, hence asking)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Ok, I got it and I will be more specific next time, thank you.

Comment: @AnupamJain My answer is wrong and should not be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

add `valign` `middle` for `td`

```
<td valign="middle" class="text-right"><h2><span class="label label-default vcenter">Name</span></h2></td>
```

or

add this css

```
.table tbody>tr>td.vert-align
{
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<td  class="text-right vert-align"><h2><span class="label label-default vcenter">Name</span></h2></td>
```

Comment: Thanks - but that doesnt work since I want to vertically align the label to the center of h2 and not td.